# Colocar sub-menu debaixo da li certa

Tags: css, css3

```css
.menuAbrir, 
.menuFechar {
display:none;
}

.menuPrincipal li {
display:inline;
position: relative;
}

.menuPrincipal li a{
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:middle;
text-align:center;
width:115px;
line-height:70px;
font-size: 20px;
transition: background-color 1s;
}

.menuPrincipal li a:hover {
background-color: #63C4D3;
color: #FFFFFF;
}


.menuPrincipal li:hover > .sub-menu{
display:block;
}

.sub-menu {
display:none;
position:absolute;    
}

.sub-menu li {
display:block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menuPrincipal">
  <li><a id="mnHome" href="index.php">HOME</a></li>
  <li><a id="mnPesquisa" href="#">LOJA</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>Teste</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a id="mnContato" href="../contato.php">CONTATO</a></li>
  <li><a id="mnSobre" href="../sobre.php">SOBRE</a></li>
</ul>
```

O problema é que o submenu sai abaixo da primeira `li` e não debaixo da sua `li` correspondente.

O que fazer?

Comment: teste aqui e o sub-menu apareceu abaixo do "Loja" normalmente.

Comment: me parece normal tb e seu js `abrefecha()` esta faltando no codigo

Comment: Sim, faltou uma linha que esqueci que colocar. Olha agora fazendo favor!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O sub-menu não se alinhava ao menu loja, porque faltava um `position: relative` na classe `.mnPesquisa` e um `left: 0`(para alinhar ao menu loja) na classe `.sub-menu`. Quando vc deu position absolute no .sub-menu vc não definiu o `.mnPesquisa` como pai relativo ao `position: absolute` do `.sub-menu`.

```css
.menuPrincipal li {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
}

.menuPrincipal li a {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  width: 115px;
  line-height: 70px;
  border: #000 1px solid;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.menuPrincipal li:hover > .sub-menu {
  display: block;
}
.mnPesquisa {
  position: relative;
}
.sub-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

.sub-menu li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menuPrincipal">
  <li><a id="mnHome" href="index.php">HOME</a></li>
  <li><a id="mnPesquisa" href="#">LOJA</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>Teste</li>
      <li>Teste</li>
      <li>Teste</li>
      <li>Teste</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a id="mnContato" href="../contato.php">CONTATO</a></li>
  <li><a id="mnSobre" href="../sobre.php">SOBRE</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Então, apenas o porition:relative na li pai e left: 0;na ul sub-menu já resolveram. Não preciso mencionar o id mnPesquisa

Answer (score 1):

- O elemento `<li>` da classe ".menuPrincipal" precisa ser "position: relative" pra controlar o posicionamento de um elemento com "position: absolute" dentro dele, evitando que ele se perca no documento;
- "box-sizing: border-box" é essencial em praticamente todo documento (pelo menos eu uso bastante, e está presente inclusive no Bootstrap).

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.menuPrincipal li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.menuPrincipal li a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 115px;
  line-height: 40px;
  border: #000 1px solid;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.menuPrincipal li .sub-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(100% - 1px);
  left: 0;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 0;
}
.menuPrincipal li:hover .sub-menu {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.menuPrincipal li .sub-menu li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menuPrincipal">
  <li><a id="mnHome" href="index.php">HOME</a></li>
  <li><a id="mnPesquisa" href="#">LOJA</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>Teste1</li>
      <li>Teste2</li>
      <li>Teste3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a id="mnContato" href="../contato.php">CONTATO</a></li>
  <li><a id="mnSobre" href="../sobre.php">SOBRE</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>Teste1</li>
      <li>Teste2</li>
      <li>Teste3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Opa, tudo bom?

Eu sou novo na área e descobri duas formas de deixar embaixo da propriedade.

1) Tag Margin:
.sub-menu li {
margin-left: 120px;
}

2) Tag Float:
.sub-menu li {
float: 120px;
}

Na minha visão, eu utilizaria a tag float.

Espero ter ajudado, abraços.